# How to enforce weakSelf is used inside a block

Tags: ios, clang, objective-c-blocks, llvm-clang

Does anyone know how the enforce that weakSelf be used inside a block?

I have a basic block that we pust weakSelf inside for a custom object. If we use "self" instead of weakSelf it will cause a retain cycle.

The issue is that for some reason there is no warning when we do this. I know it should but it doesn't seem to always be the case. I'd like a way to enforce, even prevent compilation, when someone uses self inside the block.

I saw some stuff about disabling the warning, but I haven't seen anything about enabling the warning or making it an error. Without the warning it's too easy to accidentally retain self.

```
^(void){

self.foo; < I want to prevent this.
weakSelf.bar;
weakSelf.baz;
};
```

Edit: To clarify, I am not asking about how to use weakSelf or anything of the sort. I am trying to just make sure that there is a warning or error in the case that someone puts self inside the block.

Comment: if there is no warning, you probably won't create a possible retain cycle. not every strong reference to `self` inside a block causes retain cycle automatically – it depends on the workflow as well.

Comment: If you use weakify/strongify you can just use self inside of the block and it will be weak. http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html

Comment: holex, yes we are in this case creating a very bad retain cycle. It's not that I need to know how to use weakself. People working on the same project make mistakes and put self directly in the block and I'd like to have that flagged in the compiler